# Azure DevOps - Gather a list of repositories that "Require Reviewers" on PRs and for what branches

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps is their a way to gather a list of repositories that enforce "Required Reviewers on pull requests and for what branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Configurations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest to get the repositories and branches that enforces "Required Reviewers" on pull requests.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations?policyType={policyType}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

The ID of above "policyType" for Required Reviewers is "fd2167ab-b0be-447a-8ec8-39368250530e" (You can list all the policyTypes by using [Types - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api) See below screenshot:

[image]

So you can change above rest api to below:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations?policyType=fd2167ab-b0be-447a-8ec8-39368250530e&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

See below result example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works. I also found another way to do it which is found here: https://vinijmoura.medium.com/how-to-viewing-which-repositories-have-branch-policies-on-azure-devops-c9bfb370401e and takes about 15-20min to run in powershell once setup.